# ipa file is generated in the release mode but not in ad-hoc mode

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipa

I am trying to generate my ipa via Mac agent in Visual Studio. When I choose the release mode, it is ok and the Visual Studio shows me this message:

> The ipa file should be visibile on the build server.

But when I try it in ad-hoc mode, it just tells me this error:

> ipa file was not generated. please check the project configuration

I tried the different solutions, for example, I change some configurations in info.plist. But the error is still there. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have enabled the build in the project configuration.

- open project properties
- select iOS IPA Options
- change configuration to Ad-Hoc
- change platform to iPhone
- enable Build ad-hoc/enterprise package (IPA)

[image]

Comment: have you deleted `bin, obj` of the project and the `mtbs` folder (on Mac: /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/)? And rebuilt?

Comment: Do you mean to exclude the bin and obj folder from my solution. They are already elcluded.

Comment: No just completely deleting them. VS is caching alot and trying to avoid unnecessary rebuilds. Unfortunately, sometimes the caching is too much ^^ Just delete the 3 folders I mentioned, and try again. Don't worry, they are just temporary build output folders.

Comment: Thanks for your responss. I aldo did it, but still it shows the last error.

Comment: I have the same problem. Has a solution been found?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the problem for some hours I found - in my case - there were  some problem with my Apple developer account handling in Visual Studio and that's why VS could not find any certificates to sign / generate ipa.

So, pls check your Apple developer account settings in VS options (Tools/Options/Xamarin/Apple accounts) After reentering my credentials IPA is generated in my case.